# not returning result value in following code..What is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net

not return result in following code..What is missing in the following code.
it should return true if all (dropdownlist or textbox)controls are not empty.
or return false if all are empty.
i am new to c# so Please Help.

```
    bool IsValidate(Control c,bool result)
    {
        foreach (Control x in c.Controls)
        {
            IsValidate(x,result);
        }
        if (c is DropDownList)
        {
            DropDownList d = (DropDownList)c;
            if (d.SelectedValue.Equals("0") || d.SelectedValue.Equals(""))
            {
                result = false;
            }
            else
            {
                result = true;
            }
        }
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox t = (TextBox)c;

            if (t.Text.Equals(""))
            {
                result = false;
            }
            else
            { 
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
}
```

Comment: I see you're doing some recursion,.  `foreach (Control x in c.Controls) IsValidate(x,result);`
        Did you intend to do that?  Have you stepped through it with a debugger?

Comment: can you please put code from which you are calling this method that will help to understand your code properly.

Comment: Also, there is no point in `bool result` as a function parameter.  You can define it inside your function with `bool result = false;`.  C# passes primitive values by value, such as booleans, not by reference.

Comment: You'll need to explain your problem in more detail. Your code might be crashing if there is no SelectedValue for the DropDownList case, as `d.SelectedValue.Equals(...)` will result in a `NullReferenceException`, because `d.SelectedValue` would be `null`. To deal with this, add a check `d.SelectedValue != null`.

Comment: You are calling the function recursively, but you are doing nothing with the result of the recursive call.  Also you need to think about your logic.  If it returns true if all are not empty, and false if all are empty, what should it return if some are empty and some not?

Answer (score 0):

You must return the result as soon as validation failed. You keep validating other controls which might setting the result variable to true again. I'd change your code a bit which might be helpful:

```
//You dont need another parameter
bool IsValidate(Control c)
{
    foreach (Control x in c.Controls)
    {
        var result = IsValidate(x);

        //Return instantly if validation failed
        if (!result) return false;
    }
    if (c is DropDownList)
    {
        DropDownList d = (DropDownList)c;
        return !(string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.SelectedValue) || d.SelectedValue.Equals("0"));
    }
    else if (c is TextBox)
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(((TextBox)c).Text);

    //Return true if control is neither a textbox or dropdownlist
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Use "as" (Type) inside the if statements instead to remove casting